# "http is a type and can not be used as an expression" VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble with a program that I'm trying to make. The program is supposed to play an mp3 file from a URL, but I keep getting an saying "http is a type and can not be used as an expression". I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour, but I can't. I tried Google to see if there might be a solution to my problem, but I couldn't find anything to fix my problem.

```
Imports System.Net.WebRequestMethods
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = http://keygenjukebox.com/?i=ACME_-_UltraEdit_12.xkg.mp3
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a VB expert, but I'd guess that URL has to go in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You have forgotten to wrap the string in quotes:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "http://keygenjukebox.com/?i=ACME_-_UltraEdit_12.xkg.mp3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but now I get this error when I debugged my program: 

Files has invalid value "obj\x86\Debug\Aiseesoft Video Converter Ultimate v6.3.6 Patch.vbproj.ResolveComReference.cache". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters. Aiseesoft Video Converter Ultimate v6.3.6 Patch

Comment: You might want to ask a different question since it seems to be a different issue. The file name is too long, isn't it?

Comment: Usually I get that error before I even start creating the project. Why the heck would it tell me that now though? OK, I'll try renaming it and I'll see if that works.